# How to pass service returned data as an input of child component? Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-services

I am trying to pass data that I am getting from my service call to the input of my child component but its always undefined or null. I have figured out the reason but don't know how to solve. The reason in my opinion is when the child component is rendered, the (uninitialized) variable is not yet set by the HTTP call so it gets passed uninitialized.

My parent component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'live-auction',
    templateUrl: BaseConfigurations.baseTemplatePath + '/live/index.html',
    providers: [AuctionService]
})
export class LiveAuctionComponent {
    private auction: CarAuction = new CarAuction();

    public initialize() {
        this.getCarAuction();
    }

    getCarAuction(): void {
        this.auctionservice.getCarAuctions().subscribe(auction => {
                this.auction = auction;
            },
            error => this.onError(error));
    }
}
```

Child component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'sellers-upcoming-auctions',
    templateUrl: BaseConfigurations.baseTemplatePath + '/auctions/upcoming/sellerAuctions.html',
    inputs: ['sellerid', 'take']
})

export class SellerUpcomingAuctionsComponent extends BaseConfigurations {
    private sellerid: string;
    private take: number;

    public initialize() {
        console.log(this.sellerid);
    }

    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}
```

In my index.html (parent's component template)

```
<h3>Parent Template</h3>
<sellers-upcoming-auctions [sellerid]="auction.SellerUserId" take="4"></sellers-upcoming-auctions>
```

This line below:

```
[sellerid]="auction.SellerUserId"
```

should somehow pass the updated value (or wait for http call to return response). Something like promise or observeable might be a solution but I don't know how?

Thank you

Comment: I suggest you take a look at this, you can apply it directly to your code, just changing the variables and properties :) https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-child The only thing you might have to do, is to set an `*ngIf` statement in your child-template that waits that the data is retrieved :)

Comment: sorry, "child-template" was not the word I was looking for, mean the child-tag in your parent template :) Otherwise it's pretty the same, just adding http in the mix!

Comment: @AJT_82 That's perfect. I feel stupid missing something this simple. I have added *ngIf="auction.SellerUserId" and it worked Thanks :)

Comment: You are welcome! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per discussed in comments, just add a `*ngIf` statement to your child-component tag in your parent, that waits that data is retrieved, so you won't get an error!

```
<sellers-upcoming-auctions *ngIf="auction" [sellerid]="auction.SellerUserId" take="4"></sellers-upcoming-auctions>
```